# Live stream gopro 4 footage to a web app

Tags: python, django, web-applications, video-streaming, gopro

I've got a fun question for you guys. I want to build a web app, preferably in python/django that takes live streaming footage from a gopro camera and posts it to my site.

Whats your opinion on ffmpeg, nginx or using a Livestream/Ustream api? A 10-20 second delay would still fit my needs.

Comment: Dear Sir, im very interested in this too! Can you point out what you have discovered so far?